# SoX suggestions - Binaural Beats?

Tags: command-line, sound, alsa, sox

I got so inspired by this question [Generate white noise to calm a baby](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789465/generate-white-noise-to-calm-a-baby), and was wondering if [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) could be used for generating [Binaural Beats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binaural_beats).

Basically I'd want to make sounds that are such that there is a between 2 Hz to 20 Hz difference between the tone in the left and right channel.

- The tone(s) may change be of different type - sine, square, sawtooth, ...
- The tone(s) may change in pitch - grow to lower frequency
- The difference between the tone(s) may change - go from far apart (eg. 16 Hz) to closer apart (eg. 4 Hz)
- Ideally it would be great to play several "sets" simultaneously - eg. 500 Hz +/- 15 Hz, 300 +/- 8 Hz, 200 +/- 4 Hz

Additionally it would be great if some additional sound may be played - like soft music or those waves from the "calm a baby"-question.

Speaking of the waves, would it be possible to get them slightly out-of-pitch and/or out-of-sync?  One channel with slightly lower frequency than the other?  (Hmmm... I guess white-noise is *all* frequencies, and thus have no pitch...)  Or having the "breaking wave" noise in one channel start slightly before the other?

I know there are programs - and websites - that does this (I've got several of them)...  This is more of a "can it be done"...  If I should bother trying to learn SoX well enough to succeed - and if there are some good tips to get me started.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`synth` generates left and right tones:

```
play -n synth sine 520 sine 530
```