# Generate the sounds of a babbling brook or a water-fall with SoX?

Tags: command-line, sound, audio-recording, sox

I got so inspired by this question ["Generate White Noice to Calm a Baby"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789465/generate-white-noise-to-calm-a-baby), so I was wondering what else i possible to do with SoX...

- Is it possible to generate the sound of a babbling brook?
- Is it possible to generate the sound of a (large) water-fall?
- Is it possible to generate a wooden hollow sound - like of a wooden branch stinking a hollow trunk?